# Why can't TypeScript type check React props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Why isn't TypeScript able to type-check React props? The following example passes Typescript even though it is incorrect:

```
import * as React from 'react';

type ChildProps = {
  value: string
}

const Child = (props:ChildProps) => (
  <div>{props.value}</div>
)

const Parent = props => (
  <Child {... props} />
)

const BadParent = <Parent />; // incorrect behavior: passes type check even though value is missing
```

While this code passes fine:

```
import * as React from 'react';

type ChildProps = {
  value: string
}

const Child = (props:ChildProps) => (
  <div>{props.value}</div>
)

const Parent = props => (
  <Child />         // correct behavior: throws type error
)
```

So it seems Typescript knows what types should be passed to the Child component but doesn't know how to interpret types from props being passed in.

I know I can just change the function signature of the Parent to include the ChildProps argument type, but I'm looking for a way to avoid doing this because I need to have a different Parent defined in several different modules, which means I have to import the ChildProps type every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here type of `props` is `any` so, props.value can be a string or can be a object which is correct

```
const Parent = props => (
  <Child value={props.value} />
)
```

Here Props of Child is always undefined which is not correct

```
const Parent = props => (
  <Child />
)
```

Note: Typescript only does compile-time type checking, if you get a number inside a sting type in typescript, at run-time it will pass.

Comment: so I must include ChildProps then since the type will always be any?

Comment: yes, you can do that or you can also say

`const Parent = props => ( <Child value={props.value as ChildProps} /> )`
this will expect `props.value` to be of type `ChildProps`

Answer (score 3):

You need to type your components with `React.FC` and pass an `interface` to be merged with react props

```
interface ChildProps {
  value: string;
}

const Child: React.FC<ChildProps> = props => (
  <div>{props.value}</div>
)

const Parent: React.FC = props => (
  <Child value="val" />
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I prefer to use `type` instead of `interface`. upvote for your awesome answer.