# Restricting valid props of a react child with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have a wrapper component around some child components that I want to use to manipulate their props dynamically. My issue is I want a way to get Typescript to fail to compile when the child has an invalid props type, but can't find a way to solve it. I've set up a code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-cdn-fe3kg) and the relevant portion is in the snippet below:

```
const ValidChild = (props: TestProps) => (
  <span>
    Foo: {props.foo}, Bar: {props.bar}
  </span>
);

const InvalidChild = (props: OtherProps) => <span>Beep: {props.beep}</span>;

const ExtendedValidChild = (props: ExtendedTestProps) => (
  <span>
    Foo: {props.foo}, Bar: {props.bar}, Baz: {props.baz.toString()}
  </span>
);

const Wrapper = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactElement<TestProps> }) => {
  return React.cloneElement(children, { foo: "BEEP", bar: 2 });
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <InvalidChild beep="a" />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

type TestProps = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
};

type ExtendedTestProps = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  baz: boolean;
};

type OtherProps = {
  beep: "a" | "b";
};
```

What I would like is for typescript to compile and run when either the `ValidChild` or `ExtendedValidChild` components are provided to the `Wrapper` component, but fail when the `InvalidChild` component is supplied. I'm at a loss as to where I can go from here so any help would be most welcome.

Edit:

After further investigating it looks like this is an extant issue that others have faced as can be seen in the comments of the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475309/how-do-i-restrict-the-type-of-react-children-in-typescript-using-the-newly-adde). I'd still like a solution if anyone can help, but it looks like it's a long standing niche issue that might not have a potential solution.

Comment: `InvalidChild: FC<OtherProps> = ...`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't TypeScript type check React props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57685744/why-cant-typescript-type-check-react-props)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm afraid that doesn't work, typing it as `React.FC<OtherProps>` still results in it passing type checking when passed as a child of `Wrapper`. Also the link provided also doesn't seem to work either I'm afraid.